# Hide Tab in ViewNavigator in Flex/Flash Builder?

Tags: apache-flex, view, tabs, flash-builder, hide

I want to hide a Tab in ViewNavigator, is this possible?

The thing is I want to have a View and a ViewNavigator, but I don't want to have the View as a Tab in the Navigator.

In other words I want to have a View that the user cannot reach from the Tabs in the Navigator. Simply a View/ViewNavigator without being a Tab in the menu.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just set visible=false and includeInLayout=false on your Tab.